# Adding an Event Listener for Uploading a File that 'Fires' every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-listener

I am trying to upload an excel file to my react app. I am using an event listener but it is only "picking up" the data the first time I upload a file. For example, I start my local server and then upload a file, `test1.xlsx` this works correctly. I then upload a second file, `test2.xlsx`. This also works. However, now if I try to upload either `test1.xslx` or `test2.xlsx`. Nothing will appear in the console. My code is as follows:

```
const input = document.getElementById('input-data')
    if(input){
        input.addEventListener('change', () => {
            var data = [];
            readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then((rows) => {
                data.push(rows)
            })
            console.log(data)
        })
    }
```

I am fairly new to all this so I am not sure if there is an event listener other than `'change'` that would be better or if it is something to due with how the browser is storing the data. Let me know!

Comment: "load" may be what you want:  input.addEventListener("load", () => {...})

Comment: I think you should show your JSX code too. How are you calling this function and anything else that you think might affect the behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had success with this (only showing skeleton, but using this structure to load images):

```
<input onInput={onSelectFile} type="file" ... />
```

and

```
const onSelectFile = (e) => {
  const onLoadFn = (dataURL) => {
    // processing goes here, maybe something like
    setImage(dataURL);
  };

  if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => onLoadFn(reader.result));
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    // setState etc could go here, something like
    setDialogOpen(true);
  }
};
```